# Is SPNEGO support a pre-requisite for NTLM support?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, ntlm, spnego

I just learned that a certain application which am exploring does not support SPNEGO authentication. Does this mean that Microsoft's NTLM is also not supported?

Here's a blurb from [the wiki page on SPNEGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPNEGO) that makes me believe the above is true:

> "...SPNEGO's most visible use is in Microsoft's "HTTP Negotiate"
>   authentication extension. It was first implemented in Internet
>   Explorer 5.01 and IIS 5.0 and provided single sign-on capability later
>   marketed as Integrated Windows Authentication. The negotiable
>   sub-mechanisms included NTLM and Kerberos, both used in Active
>   Directory..."

For reference, [link to the NTLM wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager)

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. Security APIs support distinct mechanisms which can be queried upfront. If SPNEGO is not available dot not necessary mean that you cannot do NTLM. If NTLM is not available, SPNEGO definitely won't fall back to NTLM if Kerberos fails.